# How to only intialize new values on software update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to init some Variables when the Unity game open for the first time

I have tried this

```
private void Awake()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Onfirst") == 0)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Onfirst", 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < CHbutton.Count; i++)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buyCH" + MenuNum.ToString() + i.ToString(), 0);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selectCH" + MenuNum.ToString() + i.ToString(), 0);
        }
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buyCH" + MenuNum.ToString() + '0', 1);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selectCH" + MenuNum.ToString() + '0', 1);
    }
}
```

I'm using such a thing in many classes, the problem is on software updates, if I want to add any init Variables like this I have to add this script again and leave the first one because of the new users,

explaining this issue see this line

```
private void Awake() // let's say a player open the game and this Script done
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Onfirst") == 0)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Onfirst", 1);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("firstUpdate", 1);
    }
}
```

on the new software update

```
private void Awake() 
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Onfirst") == 0)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Onfirst", 1);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("firstUpdate", 1);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SecUpdate", 1);
    }
}
```

now when the player update the Game, he will never receive these changes,
so to solve this

```
private void Awake() 
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Onfirst") == 0)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Onfirst", 1);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("firstUpdate", 1);
    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Onfirst2") == 0)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Onfirst2", 1);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SecUpdate", 1);
    }
}
```

and so on

let's say I'm using about 10 Scripts like above(cannot be merged), after many updates, I can't handle all of these lines,

what I really want is something like init Script every software update, but without resetting values that already exist.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!
  OP: _"...and yes `it works fine`, but is there any `better way` to do this?"_

Comment: maybe I should give more explanation about the last line, I'm gonna edit the question and then decide

Comment: I'd use a static class with a static initializer to hold those values.  You will need some form of persistence if the values are changing.

Comment: There IS actual problem: code works fine just for first few updates, but it isn't supportable for a long term.

Comment: About terminology: "update" is a software update, like new version - not the unity's Update() function, right?

As I got, you need to execute some code after every (or particular) update. If so, I think, you can use incremental update number instead of booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HasKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.HasKey.html) to check if these variables have already been set. If they have already been set, just don't initialize them:

```
private void Awake() 
{
    // first update
    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("firstUpdate")) 
    { 
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("firstUpdate", 1); 
    } 

    // second update
    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("secondUpdate")) 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("secondUpdate", 1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: you know, it's the first time I see this get method "HasKey", that.s really what I want, thank you for the help

Comment: @MohamedAwad Glad I could help. Consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) this answer to help people with a similar question find this answer easier. It also gives me some more reputation points :)